# Solver Foundation with net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ms-solver-foundation

Actually I´m working with a project based on Net Core 5.0 (preview).

I need to use Solver Foundation but, as the Solver is based on .Net Framework (where it´s working well), does not want to work.

When I try to initialize it with:

```
var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
```

I get following error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'
```

Some body can suggest a workaround ?

Thank you in advance,

Piercarlo

Comment: You **cannot** use a .NET Framework library from a .NET Core project. If you really need to use Solver Foundation you'll need to target .NET Framework with your project. It might however be worth looking into an alternative to Solver Foundation that supports .NET Core projects

Comment: Microsoft Solver Foundation received its [last update in 2012](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/04/echos-from-past-ms-solver-foundation.html) and was discontinued from Microsoft?